# Using R to create a function,. to return the corresponding quarter of a specific date

Tags: r

I need to create a function called date_quarter that accepts any vector of dates as its input and then returns the corresponding quarter for each date

Examples:

- “2019-01-01” should return “Q1”
- “2011-05-23” should return “Q2”
- “1978-09-30” should return “Q3”

etc.

Using the flights data set from the nycflights13 package in R to test the function by creating a new column called quarter using mutate.

Tried to make the function, but it doesn't return the quarter.

Comment: The [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) package has a `quarter()` function.

Comment: Try `quarters.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2011-05-23", "1978-09-30"))`.

Comment: Andre, it needs to be in a function, not entering it manually.

Comment: That's just a literal example. `quarters.Date()` is the function. Just give it any vector, e.g. `quarters.Date(data$Dates)`

Comment: It's not `lubridate::quarters`; it's`quarter`.

Comment: Or its `base::quarters.Date`. However, the code in your comment suggests you think there exists `nycflights13::flights$date`, which I cannot find in my version of `nycflights13`. Perhaps you can use `flights %>% mutate(qrtr = quarters(time_hour)))` or `flights %>% mutate(date = as.Date(time_hour), quarter = quarters(date))`. Or you can change my `quarters(date)` to `lubridate::quarter(date)` and get an integer 1-4 instead. Either way, I think your question is answered (at least what goes into your function is resolved ... formation of it is fairly straight-forward from here).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out,

```
date_quarter <- function(dates){
  quarter = quarters.Date(dates)
  result = str_c(quarter)
  return(result)
}
```